# Counting the Pagination and then removing content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image slider that as pagination on it and I want to remove the first 0 character when it reaches 10. So I want it to say 10 not 010. I am sure there are a number of ways of doing it, but not sure which way is best. Something like find number of elements and then if reaches to 10 `.replace`, but everything I tried doesn't seem to work.

```
var Pagnum = $('div a').length;
var PagContent = $('div a').text();

if (pagnum =< 10) {
  pagcontent.replace('0',''); 
}
```

example

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 010
```

Change to this

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure javascript solution, you don't need jQuery for that. jQuery increases load on your server! It's good to use javascript whereever possible!

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ukYw9/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pagination_nums">
 <span>01</span>
 <span>02</span>
 <span>03</span>
 <span>04</span>
 <span>05</span>
 <span>06</span>
 <span>07</span>
 <span>08</span>
 <span>09</span>
 <span>010</span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('span').length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].innerHTML) >= 10) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].innerHTML.replace("0", " ");
    }
}
```

It will work for any range!

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('bx-pager-item a').length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('bx-pager-item a')[i].innerHTML) >= 10) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('bx-pager-item a')[i].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('bx-pager-item a')[i].innerHTML.replace("0", " ");
    }
}
This doesn't work. :(

Comment: I had to chanege to the  etElementsByClassName and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(pagnum.length>2){
   pagnum = pagnum.substr(1);
}
```

it will work with digits from 10 to 99 only ..

Comment: http://sc.michaelscimeca.com/typography/stand-up-to-cancer-2/ Heres is what it is doing? Do i need to add the script in the js file that is creating the pag?

Comment: @Kelly what bout my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, will work with any number starting with `zero` and with more than `2` digits, otherwise the number will be the same.

For example: **09999**, **0888**, **077**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var num = "010"; //Change this value
    var page = (num.length > 2) ? num.slice(1) : num;

    alert(page);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var Pagnum = "010";///as for example
 var digit;
 if(Pagnum.length >2)
 {
   digit=parseInt(Pagnum );
  alert(digit);

 }


});
```

It will wrok for any number greater than 09 in  this case.